# The flask application does not see the javascript runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I need to run some javascript code in a flask application, I use pyexecjs for this, but it constantly gives an error:

```sh
execjs._exceptions.RuntimeUnavailableError: Could not find an available JavaScript runtime.
```

I tried to repeat the search for executable files as in [the source code of the pyexecjs](https://github.com/doloopwhile/PyExecJS/blob/master/execjs/_external_runtime.py#L198):

```py
import os
import sys
import stat

import execjs
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, current_app

common = Blueprint(name='common', import_name=__name__)

@common.route(rule='/')
def index():
    os.environ["PATH"] += f':/usr/bin:/usr/bin/node'
    pathlist = os.environ.get('PATH', '').split(os.pathsep)
    current_app.logger.info(pathlist)

    for dir in pathlist:
        for ext in ("",):
            filename = os.path.join(dir, 'node' + ext)

            try:
                st = os.stat(filename)
                current_app.logger.info(st)
            except os.error:
                continue

            current_app.logger.info(stat.S_ISREG(st.st_mode))
            current_app.logger.info(stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode) & 0o111)
            if stat.S_ISREG(st.st_mode) and (stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode) & 0o111):
                current_app.logger.info(filename)
            else:
                current_app.logger.info('false')

    current_app.logger.info(execjs.eval("'red yellow blue'.split(' ')"))

    return render_template('doc.html')
```

```sh
[2021-06-04 21:10:14,861] INFO in common_routes: ['/home/psapi//.venv/bin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/bin/node']
[2021-06-04 21:10:14,861] INFO in common_routes: os.stat_result(st_mode=33261, st_ino=1325957, st_dev=64514, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=74253640, st_atime=1622834352, st_mtime=1620756851, st_ctime=1622834318)
[2021-06-04 21:10:14,862] INFO in common_routes: True
[2021-06-04 21:10:14,862] INFO in common_routes: 73
[2021-06-04 21:10:14,862] INFO in common_routes: /usr/bin/node
[2021-06-04 21:10:14,862] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/psapi/app/common_routes.py", line 33, in index
    current_app.logger.info(execjs.eval("'red yellow blue'.split(' ')"))
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/execjs/__init__.py", line 51, in eval
    return get().eval(source, cwd)
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/execjs/_runtimes.py", line 21, in get
    return get_from_environment() or _find_available_runtime()
  File "/home/psapi/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/execjs/_runtimes.py", line 49, in _find_available_runtime
    raise exceptions.RuntimeUnavailableError("Could not find an available JavaScript runtime.")
execjs._exceptions.RuntimeUnavailableError: Could not find an available JavaScript runtime.
```

As you can see it finds nodejs executables, but the error is still there.
There is also nodejs in the path:

```sh
(.venv) root@vm2350048:/home/psapi# echo $PATH
/home/psapi/.venv/bin:/usr/bin/node:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

What else can I do about it?

Comment: This package is end of life. It's hard to tell exactly why it doesn't find Nodejs and if it is a bug they said they will no longer patch anything. But my question is why are you using js inside your flask app? You're having it split a string which is probably more time consuming than doing it in python.

Comment: @Mythalorian I have a lot of legacy code that is difficult to port to python, so I use this.